# 'label.restricted': 'true' does not properly change the setting on the file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

In the following example from my Google Apps Script, the line to change **label.restricted** does not properly change the file property. Everything else in the snippet works as expected. Under Advanced Google Services I have turned on Drive API v2 (v3 is not available to me). Can anyone debug this?

```
function setSharing(email, fileId) {
  var body = {
    'value': email,
    'role': 'reader',
    'type': 'user'
  };
  var options1 = {
    'sendNotificationEmails': 'false',
  };
  var options2 = {
    'labels.restricted': 'true',
    'writersCanShare': 'false'
  };
  Drive.Permissions.insert(body, fileId, options1);
  Drive.Files.update(options2, fileId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a change as follows?

from

```
'labels.restricted': 'true',
```

to

```
'labels': {'restricted': true},
```